# Product of two spherical harmonics as a linear combination of spherical harmonics

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

Studying the book "Physics of Atoms and Molecules" by B.H Brandsden and C.J. Joachain I stumbled upon this given result (without any proof):

$$
Y_{m_1}^{\ell_1}Y_{m_2}^{\ell_2}=\sum_{\ell=|\ell_1-\ell_2|}^{\ell_1+\ell_2}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\sqrt{\dfrac{(2\ell_1+1)(2\ell_2+1)}{4\pi(2\ell+1)}}\langle\ell_1,\ell_2, 0,0|\ell, 0\rangle\langle\ell_1,\ell_2, m_1, m_2|\ell, m\rangle Y_{m}^{\ell}
$$

- $\ell$ is the quantum number associated with the operator $L^2$,
- $m$ is the quantum number associated with the operator $L_z$,
- $Y_{m}^{\ell}$ is the spherical harmonic associated with the quantum numbers $\ell$ and $m$,
- $\langle \ell',\ell'',m_{\ell'},m_{\ell''}|\mathcal{L},\mathcal{M}\rangle$ is shorthand notation for the Clebsh-Gordan coefficient $\langle \ell',\ell'',m_{\ell'},m_{\ell''}|\ell',\ell'',\mathcal{L},\mathcal{M}\rangle$.

I tried to get this expression a proof but with no success. Does anybody know how to prove it or some literature where to find the proof?

Comment: To me this looks a lot like the formula given in the 'Contraction rule' section of this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Contraction_rule. On the other hand, the spherical harmonics form an orthogonal (-normal?) base of  $L^2(\mathbb{S}^n)$, and what you have written down is obviously a representation of the product on the left hand side by means of that base - so it should be clear how to prove this formula by calculating the pertinent scalar product(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (3.8.72) and background sections (3.6, 3.8) of *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, by Sakurai & Napolitano (2010 Addison Wesley), ISBN-13: 978-0805382914 .

The point is
$$
\langle \theta, \phi| l,m\rangle= Y^l_m(\theta,\phi) \tag{3.6.23} 
$$
and you apply these to the Clebsch series for rotation matrix representations, directly defined through spherical harmonics, as demonstrated in
(3.8.72) of that text, well-worth reviewing.